# How to bulk Update URLs to new values?

Tags: posts, customization, post-meta, urls, site-url

How to bulk update 50 posts with old URL=https://bkfast.vn/san-pham/thiet-bi-trong-rau-sach-thuy-canh-bkfast/ to new URL=https://bkfast.vn/bo-trong-rau-thuy-canh/ ?
Tks in adv,

Comment: Search and replace in the database? Probably most efficient

Comment: yes, in database. i wanna use sql command in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Use [https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/][1] plugin for Wordpress.

Go to Tools -> Better Search Replace.

First make a backup of your database before doing any actions.

Select the necessary tables :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Run first as dry to make sure there are no issues and afterwards unclick the dry option and you can replace.
[1]: https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJUDB.png